# best way to redirect securely one domain to another in IIS without having a website

Tags: azure, http, redirect, iis, cname

I would like to know what is the best way to redirect everything from marketing-address.com to real-address.com.

**best** means

- as less effort as possible,
- as cheap as possible,
- as secure as possible.

In detail:

- **Less effort**: If possible without the need of creating a website oder some code like javascript
- **Secure**: https://marketing-address.com should be accpeted by the browsers - no warning.
- **Cheap**: if possible without buying a certificate (I don't think that this is possible) and without having a second webserver running

So in theory, the communication would be like this:

- Making the address targeting the same IP address
- Making the existing IIS listen to that address to
- Let IIS tell the caller "yes, you're totally right here, but I neither I have a website nor do I have a certificate, but you don't need anything of that since you get redirected anyway..."

Is there a chance to accomplish that? If no, I would need to buy a certificate. What would be the solution then?

There are **2 restrictions**:

1. We are using an Azure App Service for hosting an asp.net core site, which seems to be very restricted in configuration possibilities
2. The browser should definetly show the real-address.com in the URL, not the marketing-address.com.

Comment: I think whether you can complete your needs through IIS reverse proxy. For more information about IIS reverse proxy, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use an Application Gateway before the IIS/Webapp at the backend?

I believe the AppGW will solve these issues, the AppGW can redirect the hostname to another web address, as many you want to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#tls-termination